# completion of part x using n-1 parts

Tags: python, algorithm, math, xor

I've build a small module in python which takes a list of strings/buffers in the same size, and returns a `xor` string in the same size. Then, using that string, together with `n-1` strings, I can complete the missing one.
It works great, so my question is:

1. do you know an already made python module for that?
2. is there a way (practically/theory) where i can complete 2 missing strings using the other n-2 strings:

Lets say i have 4 strings:

> a. "hello"
>   b. "sight"
>   c. "robin"
>   d. "about"

Is there a way to build a new string in the same size (or a little bigger) that if i have that string and also 2 strings for example 'a' and 'b' i could complete 'c' and 'd'?

Comment: Isn't something from here helpfull for your point 2? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) There is unlikely to be a published module for that.

(2) I think that you mean that `a ^ b ^ c ^ d == e`, and you ask if the values of c and d can be recovered  ("completed") if the values of a b and e are known. The answer to that question is no -- you have one equation with two unknowns.

**Update** in response to question "so if i understand you correctly there is no better solution than the XOR thing i did?"

No, I was pointing out that using XOR allowed recovery of only one missing string. You may wish to do a web search for "error correcting codes".

Comment: (1) i'm not talking only for python, but generally - even c/pp  
(2) that's for sure, but i mean is there another trick that can be done mathematically.  or lets say, complete 2/10 parts using the other 8 parts.

Comment: @RoeeK: (1) I answered your more general (any language) question. (2) No means no. 2 missing out of 10 has the same problem as 2 missing out of 4: fewer equations than unknowns.

Comment: so just to make sure, here is an analogy:
i have 10 parts in one side of the river and need to take them to the other side. when i'm in side A, i can build a new part in the same size (we now call it part X), based on all other parts and ship it safely to side B. then 10 boats ship 10 parts, but some boats might fall. so the question is actually: what algorithm should i use to build part X, in way that i could use the minimum number of arrived parts to complete all the rest? so if i understand you correctly there is no better solution than the XOR thing i did?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to find such pairs is simple - for every possible 'c' find matching 'd'. You'll get many solutions. Obviously you can't get single pair ('c', 'd') because then you could switch one bit in both strings (the same bit in both) and get different solution.